# How do I make ADB work on linux with a motorola

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, adb

As the title says, I am having difficulty using ADB on linux. I have a motorola Droid X shadow running gingerbread 2.3.4. I have a laptop with Ubuntu 13.04. I need to be able to establish a connection from the computer to the phone, using ADB.

1. I installed ADB from google (into ~/android-sdk-linux)
2. I put the phone into debugging (settings -> applications -> development -> usb debugging)
3. I installed the [udev rules](http://codeworkx.de/wordpress/linux-scripts/linux-adb-udev-rules/). (see [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html) for more info)
4. I restarted the computer and the phone
5. I connected the two (phone says that it is charging)
6. I tried ./adb devices

I got an empty device list

```
sam@Aristotle:~$ ls -ahl /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules 

    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2.7K Jun 19 14:03 /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules

sam@Aristotle:~$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules 
    <!-- snip -->
    SUBSYSTEM==”usb”, ATTR{idVendor}==”22B8″, MODE=”0666″, GROUP=”plugdev”
    <!-- snip -->
```

Then I restart the machine. Once it is up I plugin the phone.

```
root@Aristotle:/home/sam/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools# ./adb devices
    List of devices attached 

root@Aristotle:/home/sam/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools# ./adb kill-server
root@Aristotle:/home/sam/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools# ./adb start-server
    * daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
    * daemon started successfully *
root@Aristotle:/home/sam/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools# ./adb devices
    List of devices attached 

root@Aristotle:/home/sam/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools#
```

I did try this as user 'sam' too (sam is in plugdevs). I also tried this with multiple USB ports on my laptop.

I was thinking that I could use something like [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.wifiadb&hl=en) to communicate with the phone over wifi, but that requires rooting, and the only 'safe' methods of rooting require adb.

I turned on Udev debugging and tried it again. Then I opened /var/log/udev. It was pretty long, so I searched up '22b8' (not case sensitive), because according to [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html), that is the USB Vendor ID for motorola, but my search could not find any results. I don't think the rule I put /etc/udev/rules.d/ is firing for some reason.

Output to `sudo lsusb -vv` is found [here](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33591459/lsusb.txt) (too long to post).

I also tried installing p2kmoto

```
root@Aristotle:/home/sam/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools# p2ktest 
P2k Test
Device list:
1d6b:0001: [Linux 3.8.0-26-generic ohci_hcd] [OHCI Host Controller]
0461:4d16: [] [USB Optical Mouse]
1d6b:0001: [Linux 3.8.0-26-generic ohci_hcd] [OHCI Host Controller]
1d6b:0001: [Linux 3.8.0-26-generic ohci_hcd] [OHCI Host Controller]
1d6b:0001: [Linux 3.8.0-26-generic ohci_hcd] [OHCI Host Controller]
04f2:b044: [Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd.] [CNF7017]
1d6b:0002: [Linux 3.8.0-26-generic ehci_hcd] [EHCI Host Controller]
1d6b:0002: [Linux 3.8.0-26-generic ehci_hcd] [EHCI Host Controller]
No phone found.
```

Comment: what's the output of lsusb? Is the usb developer option still enabled after rebooting the phone?

Comment: you have run adb with root permissions - your problem has nothing to do with the udev rule (which only allows adb access to regular users)

Comment: usually the 'non-root' problem manifests as device detected but status = ??????

Comment: @QuentinSwain Here is lsusb output: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33591459/lsusb.txt

Comment: there are no android devices in your lsusb output. even if the phone shows as charging - I would try another USB cable.

Comment: I have the exact same problem with my Moto G. I am using a USB cable that I used for debugging another Android device, so I think the problem is not in the cable...

Answer (score 1):

From the result of lsusb, it seems there is no android device shown. Did you enable usb debugging on your phone? You might want to check this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_8C-O51n7B8) for details.

Comment: In addition to enabling usb debugging. If running 4.2.2 it's necessary to authorize the machine that the device is connected to when prompted by the device.

Comment: The thing *is* in usb debugging mode. I restarted the phone, it still is in debugging mode. I am running 2.3.4. Nothing has changed in the `lsusb` output. What exactly am I looking for in the lsusb output?