# Cannot get sample-Groceries to run on connected android phone

Tags: android, linux, android-emulator, nativescript

When I execute the command: `tns run android` I got "`Could not find an emulator image to run your project.`"

I have a android phone `Motorola Moto E (2nd Gen) with 4G LTE` and it is running android 6 (Marshmellow)

My PC is running `Linux mint 18.1 Cinnanmon`. The phone is connected to the PC via a USB Cable and the phone is set to `MTP`and I can see the phone directories in the PC File Manager at `mtp://[usb:001,011]/Internal%20Storage`

I have install `nativescript` according the instructions `docs.navtivescript.org/start/ns-setup-linux`.
The `Sample-Groceries` has been downloaded and installed at `$HOME/programming/nativescript/`

tns doctor says "`No issues were detected.`"

When I execute the command: `tns run android`

I got this exception :

```
Could not find the an emulator image to run your project
```

Why is is it looking for an `emulator image`. I want it to run on my phone?

Comment: It looks for emulator image because for some reason adb is not seeing your device - use ```tns device``` to make sure your device is recognized and in connected state by adb.

Comment: Look at this thread where USB drivers for recognizing MOTO-E by ads are provided http://www.teamandroid.com/2015/06/24/moto-e-2015-usb-drivers-download/

Comment: Thank you Nick for your reply I tried tns device it does not find any connected devices I also tried adb devices that also failed to find any devices Then I tried adb kill-server and adb start-server but it still can't find any devices. The drivers you mention are for mac and windows not Linux.

Comment: take a look at this discussion - possible solution by enabling USB debugging is shown http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17456032/how-do-i-make-adb-work-on-linux-with-a-motorola

Comment: Thank you Nick following the instructions to manually setup the phone and enable USB debugging means the program now runs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make ADB work on linux with a motorola](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17456032/how-do-i-make-adb-work-on-linux-with-a-motorola)